# Is it correct to say "This Lego toy is interesting. You can mix and match different Lego blocks to create different stories"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

My children love this kind of Lego toy because it is very flexible.

For example, a prince/princess is not a whole piece as they made arms, legs, dresses, hair (**the parts**) separately. And, you can "**mix and match**" these parts to create many different versions of a prince or a princess.

For example, if you don't want the prince's blue hair, you can use the red hair.

This makes children more creative.

I am not sure I can use the phrase "**mix and match**"?

For example, would it be correct to say "**This Lego toy is interesting. You can mix and match different Lego blocks to create different stories**"?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. *Normally*, the term ***mix and match*** implies ***combining complementary items from different sources***. But in your specific context the supplier has included interchangeable components in a single product, and I don't think English has any special term distinguishing this from contexts where you're combining pieces from actual different Lego sets (or indeed other "building block" toys from other companies using the same size & shape interlocking mechanism).

Comment: The part about the prince might be a red hair-ing.

Comment: Hey @FumbleFingers. Why don't you like to give answers in the answer box?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly acceptable use of the phrase "[mix and match](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mix_and_match)". There's nothing wrong with it, and likely not a lot of ways to improve your word choice here.

At first I thought [gotube's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302132/is-it-correct-to-say-this-lego-toy-is-interesting-you-can-mix-and-match-differ#comment564330_302132) about some aspect of your question being a "red hair-ing" was a bad sign (because "red herring" is a phrase often used to describe things that are misleading), but upon more careful examination, it's just a (very) clever joke intended to incite laughter, by playing with the words "hair" and "herring".